# Implement SSL connection in JDBC producer

Tags: mysql, jdbc, streamsets

I was wondering if there's any way to implement SSL connection for JDBC producer in StreamSets, I've been looking on the net and docs, but couldn't find any info about it and the task doesn't have a TLS tab to configure it.

If it helps I'm using StreamSets DC v3.16.1 and connecting to Cloud SQL instance (MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not supported in StreamSets Data Collector.